# Why does the C# 7 discard identifier _ still work in a using block?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cil, c#-7.0

So, a pattern I use very often while working on my UWP app is to use a `SemaphoreSlim` instance to avoid race conditions (I prefer not to use `lock` as it needs an additional target object, and it doesn't lock asynchronously).

A typical snippet would look like this:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public async Task FooAsync()
{
    await Semaphore.WaitAsync();
    // Do stuff here
    Semaphore.Release();
}
```

With the additional `try/finally` block around the whole thing, if the code in between could crash but I want to keep the semaphore working properly.

To reduce the boilerplate, I tried to write a wrapper class that would have the same behavior (including the `try/finally` bit) with less code needed. I also didn't want to use a `delegate`, as that'd create an object every time, and I just wanted to reduce my code without changing the way it worked.

I came up with this class (comments removed for brevity):

```
public sealed class AsyncMutex
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    public async Task<IDisposable> Lock()
    {
        await Semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return new _Lock(Semaphore);
    }

    private sealed class _Lock : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore;

        public _Lock(SemaphoreSlim semaphore) => Semaphore = semaphore;

        void IDisposable.Dispose() => Semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

And the way it works is that by using it you only need the following:

```
private readonly AsyncMutex Mutex = new AsyncMutex();

public async Task FooAsync()
{
    using (_ = await Mutex.Lock())
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

One line shorter, and with `try/finally` built in (`using` block), awesome.

> Now, I have no idea why this works, despite the discard operator being
>   used.

That discard _ was actually just out of curiosity, as I knew I should have just written `var _`, since I needed that `IDisposable` object to be used at the end of the `using` block, and not discarder.

But, to my surprise, the same IL is generated for both methods:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void T1() cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncMutex mutex,
        [1] class System.IDisposable V_1
    )
    IL_0001: newobj       instance void System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncMutex::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0      // mutex

    IL_0007: ldloc.0      // mutex
    IL_0008: callvirt     instance class System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<class System.IDisposable> System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncMutex::Lock()
    IL_000d: callvirt     instance !0/*class System.IDisposable*/ class System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<class System.IDisposable>::get_Result()
    IL_0012: stloc.1      // V_1
    .try
    {
        // Do stuff here..
        IL_0025: leave.s      IL_0032
    }
    finally
    {
        IL_0027: ldloc.1      // V_1
        IL_0028: brfalse.s    IL_0031
        IL_002a: ldloc.1      // V_1
        IL_002b: callvirt     instance void System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_0031: endfinally   
    }
    IL_0032: ret    
}
```

The "discarder" `IDisposable` is stored in the field `V_1` and correctly disposed.

So, why does this happen? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) don't say anything about the discard operator being used with the `using` block, and they just say the discard assignment is ignored completely.

Thanks!

Comment: The IDisposable object does not have to be stored in a local explicitly. You can also just do `using(await Mutex.Lock())`.

Comment: @Wazner Wow, I had absolutely no idea about that, thanks (and it's shorter too!) ahahah  The `using` block docs page doesn't say anything about it not needing an explicit variable, and I've never seen it used that was, so I had no clue. If you post this as answer I'll be happy to mark it as valid!

Comment: FWIW, `_` is not an operator, it's an identifier.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, thanks for pointing that out, fixed 

Comment: Bit off topic, but I strongly suggest you to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` after the `await`, and remove the finalizer inside the `Lock` class.

Comment: @Yarik I often use this thing to synchronize animations in the UI, wouldn't `ConfigureAway(false)` cause crashes there, as it'd throw away the original context? Also, what's wrong with the finalizer, isn't that part of the suggested `IDisposable` implementation? Thanks!

Comment: The original context would be captured by the caller of the `Lock()` method (if needed), and will return to it when `Lock()` completes. There is no need to capture the context inside `Lock()`, since it doesn't use any UI objects. Therefore, your current implementation would cause a deadlock as soon as someone calls `Lock().Result` on the UI thread. Also, you should never try to clean up any *managed* objects inside a finalizer, because the referred object might have already been finalized. I suggest to read about the recommended `IDisposable` implementation more carefully. Good luck!

Comment: @Yarik Great, I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the heads up! 
I've fixed the class in the original question too, so future readers will see the corrected code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `using` statement does not require an explicit declaration of a local variable. An expression is also allowed.

The language specification specifies the following syntax.

> ```
> using_statement
>     : 'using' '(' resource_acquisition ')' embedded_statement
>     ;
>
> resource_acquisition
>     : local_variable_declaration
>     | expression
>     ;
> ```
>
> If the form of resource_acquisition is local_variable_declaration then the type of the local_variable_declaration must be either dynamic or a type that can be implicitly converted to `System.IDisposable`. If the form of resource_acquisition is expression then this expression must be implicitly convertible to `System.IDisposable`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement

An assignment of an existing variable (or discarding the result) is also an expression. For example the following code compiles:

```
var a = (_ = 10);
```

Answer (score 5):

The use of the discard feature is really a red herring here.  The reason that this works is because the `using` statement can accept an expression that resolves to a value to be disposed (in addition to an alternate syntax that declares a variable).  Additionally, the assignment operator *resolves to the value that is assigned*.

The value that you're providing on the right hand side of the assignment operator is your Lock object, so that's what the expression `_ = await Mutex.Lock()` resolves to.  Since that *value* (not as a variable declaration, but as a stand alone value) is disposable, it is the thing that will be cleaned up at the end of the `using`.